# USB VID and PID form Textbox

Tags: c#, usb

I get connected USB Devices from Win32 like this:

```cs
try
{
    ManagementObjectCollection collection;
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_PnpEntity where Manufacturer Like 'ATMEL%' or Manufacturer Like 'Microchip%' or Manufacturer Like 'Texas%' "))
        collection = searcher.Get();
...
}
```

The Device Informations I saved with xml serializer. Now i load the device from XML to my WPF Page and set the VID to an text box and PID to another text box.

In the next step i want to set the VID and PID to an integer value to connect the Device on this way, but i got an error:

```cs
try
{
    string _usbVID = txtUSBPNPVID.Text;
    string _usbPID = txtUSBPNPPID.Text;
    
    int usbVID = int.Parse(_usbVID, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    int usbPID = int.Parse(_usbPID, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    ...
}
```

The Error i get is:

> The input string has the wrong format

What is the correct way to pass the VID and PID from the text boxes?

Comment: could you display the content of VID/PID...?

Comment: In the text boxes yes, i see the VID and PID like 0x037B and 0x0205 as example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will use this piece of code to convert hexa beginning with 0x to int:

```
int usbVID = (int)new System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter().ConvertFromString(_usbVID);
int usbPID = (int)new System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter().ConvertFromString(_usbPID);
```

so you could create a function...

Comment: glad to help you!! dont forget to validate and upvote to close the question